# IntelliJ mac pro refactor "safe delete" unavailable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, macos-sierra

I am learning Java using IntelliJ (free version) on a Mac Pro with Sierra OS 10.12.6. Previously when I   wanted to delete unwanted projects,  I would go REFACTOR then SAFE DELETE. Now for some reason SAFE DELETE is greyed out and unavailable. Please advise. I am new to Java and this is really annoying as most of the projects I have written are not worth keeping.

Answer (score 1):

The availability of refactoring actions is determined by the current context i.e. by the currently selected artifact/class/file/method/property/whatever.

From the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea//2016.3/safe-delete.html?utm_medium=help_link&utm_source=from_product&utm_campaign=IC&utm_content=2016.3&search=safe%20delete):

> The Safe Delete refactoring lets you safely remove files and symbols from the source code.
>
> To make sure that deletion is safe, IntelliJ IDEA looks for the usages of the or symbol being deleted. If such usages are found, you can explore them and make the necessary corrections in your code before the symbol is actually deleted.

So, if you have selected any of the following then `Refactor > Safe Delete` will be enabled:

- A file in the Project tree view
- A class member in the Project tree view
- A class declaration, a method declaration, a member declaration within a class
- A property declaration in a properties file
- etc

But if you have not selected anything or if you have selected (for example) a project or a package then `Refactor > Safe Delete` will be disabled.